# Dropbox no longer works under Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dropbox

I use Ubuntu 13.10 and since yesterday my Dropbox client no longer works. A reinstallation (from Software Center) did not help. After every Ubuntu startup the client requests my admin password, but nothing happens.

Comment: This is probably a bug with the Ubuntu package that provides (some of) DropBox. I recommend [reporting it as one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). If you do, I recommend mentioning that [Thomas's workaround](http://askubuntu.com/a/404056/22949) worked (assuming it did), as that helps to clarify that the bug really probably is in the Ubuntu package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution was: Uninstall the existing Dropbox client from the Ubuntu Software Center and install the client version from the Dropbox website ( https://www.dropbox.com/install ).

Comment: As of July 2015 this solution seems to no longer work.